# how can i input a file of "access macro" in windows task scheduler?

Tags: macros, ms-access-2010, scheduled-tasks

i want to run a MSAccess-macro (Makro1) automatically using The Windows7 Tast Scheduler.
What do i Need to Input in the following Fields?

"Programm/script" and 
"Add Arguments"

I entered already the whole pfad of the macro in "program/script" and it didn´t work.

Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter the path to MSAccess.exe in the "Program/Script" field. Here is an example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
```

(Adjust this to match the actual path on your pc.)

Top start/open a database automatically, you need to put the path to the database file into the "Add Arguments" field. If you want to run a macro automatically, you should add the [/x commandline switch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209207) followed by the macro name.
Here is an example for the complete "Add Arguments" field:

```
"C:\path\to\YourDatabase.accdb" /x "YourMacroName"
```

Comment: thank you a lot , but may be i make something  wrong. are here spaces between "/x"  and  "YourMacroName" . semicolons too ? \path\to\YourDatabase.accdb" /x "YourMacroName"

Comment: Yes there should be a space between /x and the macro name. Copy the text from my answer and only change the path and name, nothing else. - There is no semicolon anywhere.